# rich:tabPanel is not rendering

Tags: jsf, richfaces, tabpanel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
                xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
                xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
                xmlns:gestenis="http://gestenis.com/jsf/facelets">

    <c:view>
        <body jsf:id="staffBody">

            <a4j:form id="pfform" >
                <h:panelGrid>
                    <rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax">
                        <rich:tab label="First">
                            Here is tab #1
                        </rich:tab>
                        <rich:tab label="Second">
                            Here is tab #2
                        </rich:tab>
                        <rich:tab label="Third">
                            Here is tab #3
                        </rich:tab>
                    </rich:tabPanel>

....
```

The result is:

Here is tab #1 Here is tab #2 Here is tab #3

All in one line, so it is not rendering it properly

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: so you are doing everything just like in their live demo and you get a different result? http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/tabPanel.jsf

Comment: I have the same issue right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

adding the of the jar dependency in the classpath (webapps/lib) without it  the rich components were not converted into the html.

Answer (score 0):

Probably mess in xml namespaces. Following should work (RichFaces 4.5.x):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:body id="staffBody">
        <h:form id="pfform" >
            <h:panelGrid>
                <rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax">
                    <rich:tab name="First">
                        Here is tab #1
                    </rich:tab>
                    <rich:tab name="Second">
                        Here is tab #2
                    </rich:tab>
                    <rich:tab name="Third">
                        Here is tab #3
                    </rich:tab>
                </rich:tabPanel>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: In my case it was the missing of the jar dependency in the classpath do the rich components were not converted into the html...